# Permissions for Camera+Images / Product data

Tags: nest-api

I've requested to "Verify company" over a month ago so that I can get permissions on my developer account to access my own camera data. Apparently verification is still pending because I still can't add this permission to my developer account.

Is nest development still supported? The @nest twitter account referred me specifically to this tag on Slack for nest API questions when I inquired what needed to be done to get verification approved.

Comment: This sort of inquiry is best handled by Nest's Developer Community at https://nestdevelopers.io/ (and yes, Nest still actively supports 3rd party development.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this issue is to request verification, REMOVE the current Camera permission, then add back the "Camera + images" permission. There can only be one permission at a time despite this not really being documented and apparently permission to add it is granted once you request verification, but this is not documented either. I was able to find something that led me to the answer over on nestdevelopers.io

Answer (score 1):

"Verify company" is only for using the [Resource Use API](https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/company-verification/). As noted above, you can only have one camera permission at a time, so depending on your camera needs, only select the one that is most appropriate.